# installment firebase-tools freezes in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase

I am working in Angular and doing a project on Udemy. As part of the project (deployment) they want me to install 'npm install firebase-tools g'. However when I try this, it freezes and it keeps displaying this message:

> C:\Users\Tijl Declerck\Desktop\projects\unFinalProjectUdemy>npm
>   install firebase-tools g [ .................] / fetchMetadata: sill
>   resolveWithNewModule isarray@0.0.1 checking installable status

The course doesn't mention this error andI can't seem to find anything online related to this? Does anyone know what I should do next?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

I went to `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`and did the command there:

> C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules>npm install -g
>   firebase-tools

Now it got installed without any issues.